# How to create a nested dictionary from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I want to create a nested dictionary from a list of lists.

**Input**:

```
[[a, b, c], [1, 'a', 'x'], [2, 'b', 'y']]
```

The main dictionary must have index as keys. The first list has the items to pass as keys to the nested dictionaries, and the following lists have the items to pass as values:

**Desired output**:

```
{0: {a:1, b:'a', c:'x'},
 1: {a:2, b:'b', c:'y'}}
```

I tried the following code, but it doesn't return each item as a nested dictionary:

```
output = {a[0]: list(a[1:]) for a in zip(*rows)}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can do it with `output = {i: dict(zip(a[0], b)) for i, b in enumerate(a[1:])}`, where `a` is your input list of lists.

Comment: But a dictionary where the keys are natural numbers in crescent order is the exact definition of a list. With that in mind, you probably really need `output = [dict(zip(a[0], b)) for b a[1:]]`,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution you can give it a try,

```
print({
    k: v for k, v in enumerate(dict(zip(val[0], v)) for v in val[1:])
})
```

---

```
{0: {'a': 1, 'b': 'a', 'c': 'x'}, 1: {'a': 2, 'b': 'b', 'c': 'y'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
>>> {i: {x: y for x, y in zip(lst[0], v)} for i, v in enumerate(lst[1:])}
{0: {'a': 1, 'b': 'a', 'c': 'x'}, 1: {'a': 2, 'b': 'b', 'c': 'y'}}
>>>
```

Or just simply:

```
>>> {i: dict(zip(lst[0], v)) for i, v in enumerate(lst[1:])}
{0: {'a': 1, 'b': 'a', 'c': 'x'}, 1: {'a': 2, 'b': 'b', 'c': 'y'}}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this bro

```
dictionary ={j: dict(zip(lst[0], i)) for j, i in enumerate(lst[1:])}
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 'a', 'x'], [2, 'b', 'y']]
{
    i: dict(zip(l[0], v)) for i, v in enumerate(l[1:])
}
```

Found one interesting way using cross product

```py
import itertools

l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 'a', 'x'], [2, 'b', 'y']]

keys = l[:1]
values_list = l[1:]

# {0: {'a': 1, 'b': 'a', 'c': 'x'}, 1: {'a': 2, 'b': 'b', 'c': 'y'}}
dict(
    # [(0, {'a': 1, 'b': 'a', 'c': 'x'}), (1, {'a': 2, 'b': 'b', 'c': 'y'})]
    enumerate(
        # [{'a': 1, 'b': 'a', 'c': 'x'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'b', 'c': 'y'}]
        map(
            lambda x: dict(zip(*x)),
            itertools.product(keys, values_list) # [(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 'a', 'x']), (['a', 'b', 'c'], [2, 'b', 'y'])]
        )
    )
)
```